# How can I delete a file from iCloud without downloading it to the device first?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, icloud, nsfilemanager

I have a basic iOS app that shows a list of documents. I'm trying to delete a document, but noticed that the code below fails with "No such file or directory" *if the document has not yet been downloaded from iCloud to the device*.

Documents can be quite large (40MB) and I'd like to avoid downloading the document only to delete it (this takes time and bandwidth out of the user's data plan). Is this possible at all?

```
[[[NSFileCoordinator alloc] initWithFilePresenter:nil]
coordinateWritingItemAtURL:documentURL
                  options:NSFileCoordinatorWritingForDeleting
         writingItemAtURL:previewURL
                  options:NSFileCoordinatorWritingForDeleting
                    error:&error
               byAccessor:^(NSURL *newDocumentURL, NSURL *newPreviewURL){

    // Fails with "No such file" error if not yet downloaded from iCloud:
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:newDocumentURL error:&error];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:newPreviewURL  error:&error];
}];
```

The full error:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The operation couldn’t be completed. 
(Cocoa error 4.)" UserInfo=0x14e82930 {NSUnderlyingError=0x14e69220 
"The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory",
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need to delete a file, use the other NSFileCoordinator coordinateWritingItemAtURL ( the one with a single newURL parameter in the accessor block ).

If you need to batch delete, then create an array of NSFileAccessIntent and use NSFileCoordinator's coordinateAccessWithIntents.

Example:

```
- ( void )deleteItemsAtURLs: ( NSArray * )urls queue: ( NSOperationQueue * )queue
{
    //assuming urls is an array of urls to be deleted
    NSFileCoordinator   * coordinator;
    NSMutableArray      * writingIntents;
    NSURL               * url;

    writingIntents = [ NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity: urls.count ];

    for( url in urls )
    {
        [ writingIntents addObject: [ NSFileAccessIntent writingIntentWithURL: url options: NSFileCoordinatorWritingForDeleting ] ];
    }

    coordinator = [ [ NSFileCoordinator alloc ] initWithFilePresenter: nil ];

    [ coordinator coordinateAccessWithIntents: writingIntents
                                        queue: queue
                                   byAccessor: ^( NSError * error )
     {
         if( error )
         {
             //handle
             return;
         }
         NSFileAccessIntent * intent;

         error = nil;

         for( intent in writingIntents )
         {
             [ [ NSFileManager defaultManager ] removeItemAtURL: intent.URL error: &error ];
             if( error )
             {
                 //handle
             }
         }
     }];
}
```

Comment: Indeed, deleting them one by one did work. So I guess it's a bug in NSFileCoordinator when trying to delete 2 files at once?

Comment: The method you were using isn't meant for batch deleting, but for follow up operations. For batch operations, see the example I gave you. Not entirely sure why it wouldn't work to delete just the 2 items, though.

Comment: How come that the answer from 2012 contains iOS8 API? It would be nice to have iOS7-compatible solution.

Comment: This solved my problem of deleting an iCloud file created by another device.  NSFileManager could not do it on its own -- needed to be wrapped in a NSFileCoordinator.  +1

Answer (score 6):

*note: Apple used to have some sample code to illustrate this but alas it has been removed.*

As has been pointed out in the answers you would need to call this method in a loop since you need a separate `NSFileCoordinator` for each file you would like to delete.

Something that I missed was that you have to call `fileManager.removeItemAtURL` with the URL of the `NSFileAccessIntent` object that you create for deleting and *not* the normal `URL` that you get access to from your `NSMetadataQueryItem`.

```
func removeFile(at url: URL, completionHandler: ((Error?) -> Void)? = nil) {
    // `url` may be a security scoped resource.
    let successfulSecurityScopedResourceAccess = url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()

    let fileCoordinator = NSFileCoordinator()
    let writingIntent = NSFileAccessIntent.writingIntent(with: url, options: .forDeleting)
    fileCoordinator.coordinate(with: [writingIntent], queue: backgroundQueue) { (accessError) in
        if accessError != nil {
            completionHandler?(accessError)
            return
        }

        let fileManager = FileManager()
        var error: Error?
        do {
            try fileManager.removeItem(at: writingIntent.url)
        }
        catch let fileError {
            error = fileError
        }
        if successfulSecurityScopedResourceAccess {
            url.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
        }

        completionHandler?(error)
    }
}
```

If you wanted to delete multiple items:

```
for url in urlsToDelete {
    removeFile(at: url)
}
```

Comment: Instead of having to create new FileManager, is there any reason not to use FileManager.default? Thanks.

Comment: @CheokYanCheng I don't see a reason why not.